# How to split lines at every intersection from a single geometry using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

The query I tried is this:

```
Create table test1 as 
  Select 
    row_number() over() as ID,
    (st_dump(st_split(input.geom, blade.geom))).geom as geom
  from roads input
  join roads blade on st_intersects(input.geom, blade.geom);
```

The error that pops up is like this:

```
ERROR:  Splitter line has linear intersection with input
SQL state: XX000
```

Comment: You must not try to split a road with itself.

Comment: I figure out a solution in QGIS. Do 'Dissolve' on the road layer first, then do 'Split with lines' and set the input layer and the split layer the same.